# Dreamweaver CS6 says my javascript file is "not defined on a local disk"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, dreamweaver, local

I'm making a site with a carousal with this tutorial:

> www.tutorialzine.com/2010/09/html5-canvas-slideshow-jquery/

I just copied and pasted the code, saved it as a JavaScript file, and copied the script source line from the tutorial to my HTML file. This is it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

However, the carousal isn't working for me (I tried to test the site using one image).  Dreamweaver says that "script.js is not defined on a local disk." What does that mean and how do I fix it? I've searched Google but I can't find the answer.

Here is my html5 code:

```
<html lang="en-us">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="keyword" content=""/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content"" />
    <meta name="copyright" content="2013" /> 
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <h1><img src="img\logo.gif" alt="print-and-copy-logo"></h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="header-about"><a href="about.html" alt="print-and-copy-about-page">about</a></li>
        <li class="header-prints"><a href="prints.html" alt="print-and-copy-the-prints-page">the prints</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="slideshow">

    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="img\photos\wedding-invitation.jpg" alt="wedding-invitation"></li>
        <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
    </ul>

    <span class="arrow previous"></span>
    <span class="arrow next"></span>

</div>

<footer>
    <ul id="footer-text">
        <li class="footer-president"> <a href="#" alt="">THE PRES</a></li>
        <li class="footer-about"> <a href="#" alt="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="footer-press"> <a href="#" alt="">PRESS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="footer-social">
        <li id="footer-twitter"><a href="#"><img src="img\icons\twitter-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li id="footer-facebook"><a href="#"><img src="img\icons\facebook-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li id="footer-tumblr"><a href="#"><img src="img\icons\tumblr-icon.png" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="footer-contact">
        <li class="footer-phone">ph: 773.488.2626</li>
        <br>
        <li class="footer-hours">hrs: mon-fri 11am-5pm</li>
    </ul>

</footer>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a file in your website in the same directory as your html page called "script.js"?

Comment: Yes, I do. That's the funny part.

Comment: As Jason said, you should make sure script.js is where you say it is. The file path in the `src=` attribute needs to say exactly where the file is on your computer.

Comment: When you view the page in your browser, check the error console and network tab for errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, after thinking about what you two  said I noticed the need for "\js." and it works. It has some bugs that need to be sorted out but the javascript is being recognized and I'll eventually sort it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Dreamweaver tutorial and the same message happened. I found out that my CSS folder needed to have a styles.css and a print.css file to be attached and the page showed up. All of the coding had been done I was just getting the error message that the local disk did not have my folder.